# Installing MySQL 5.6 Community Debug Info

Tags: mysql, installation

I have setup my yum repository as described here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/, and am wondering where I can install the debuginfo packages. Looking here http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/el/6/x86_64/ it seems there are none, but I wonder if anyone knows if I am missing something obvious.

I have already enabled /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo and have tried to do 'yum search mysql' for any such packages. I've tried asking in #mysql irc, but with no response.

Do I have to build the rpms by hand in order to get debug symbols?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/source-configuration-options.html#option_cmake_with_debug) - you can compile with debug info - it's included in the source code download.

Comment: Yes. It's disappointing that there is no package already for it.